# Xcode not allowing any classes is my custom framework in Interface Builder as custom classes

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

I have a custom class `TULabel` which derives from regular `UILabel` in my custom framework (which is another target inside the same project with my app). I have used my custom class in Interface Builder for months with no issues: I've selected a label, went to Custom Class, started typing my custom class name and it even completed itself.

I've been working on this project for long time and today I've realized I can't type `TULabel` into the custom class box anymore. I can type almost anything, even classes that don't exist. But when I try to type `TULabel` (or any other custom class from my framework) it just reverts to the previous value:

[image]

The only way for me to use my custom classes is to open up the Nib/Storyboard as source code, and type my custom class there which is, obviously, not acceptable. Weird enough, when I run my app it builds and runs correctly, with the custom label there (and I'm sure that it's the actual custom class instance and not runtime ignoring my custom class and reverting to label as it has custom drawing behavior which is displayed)

I have no idea when and where it broke since I've been working on the project for so long time and haven't tried to add a custom class for weeks.

I've tried opening and closing Xcode, cleaning my project and derived data folder, rebuilding the project but no avail. It's still the same.

Why is Interface Builder explicitly disallowing my class and how can I make Interface Builder accept my custom class name again?

I am on Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Did you try Xcode 9.3 beta 4? Did you see this happen with other frameworks?

Comment: @valcanaia no I'm on production version. it seems to happen with some classes in apparently one framework.

Comment: Are the classes marked `public` or `open`?

Comment: @AllenHumphreys I'm on Objective-C

Comment: Then are you positive the classes are being included in the umbrella header of the framework. Even if they aren't, objc runtime can still access them, but the compiler/IB won't know about them.